# Describing a Galois group for a field with the given roots adjoined

Tags: galois-theory

In this problem $\mathbb{Q}$ is viewed as a subfield of the complex numbers and a root $a = \sqrt[3]{3}$ is given.  I find the min. polynomial for this root, which is $x^3 - 3$ and I factor it into: $(x - \sqrt[3]{3})(x^2 + \sqrt[3]{3}x + \sqrt[3]{9})$.  Then by applying the quadratic formula I come up with two more roots:

$\frac{-\sqrt[3]{3}(1 \pm i\sqrt{3})}{2}$

If I let $b$ be one of these roots, then:

Thus $\mathbb{Q}(a, b)$ = $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{3}, i)$, correct?

Now, I have to describe Gal($\mathbb{Q}(a, b)$ / $\mathbb{Q}$) which will consist of all automorphisms that fix the underlying field of rationals.  Thus I will have 3 things (the things being adjoined) to permute, so the group will consist of at most 27 elements.

Does this seem right so far?  I feel like everything is okay, but I just want to make sure.

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt 3$ is already generated by the cube root.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to show this.  My basis elements would be cube root of 3 and cube root of 9 (along with 1 and i) but how would I get a square root from multiplication and division?

Comment: I think you should use $i\sqrt{3}$ as a single value to adjoin.

Comment: @Edi Madi, so $a = \sqrt[3]{3}$ and $b = i\sqrt{3}$ are enough?

Comment: Not correct in that you think $i$ is in the splitting field, and it isn’t. Nor is $\sqrt3$. What is in the splitting field is $\sqrt{-3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions of $x^3-3=0$ are $a, a\omega, a\omega^2$, where $\omega^3=1$, $\omega\ne1$.

Then $\mathbb Q(a,a\omega, a\omega^2) = Q(a,\omega)$, which has degree $6$ since $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$ and $a$ is real.

Let $\sigma: a \mapsto a\omega$ and $\tau: \omega \mapsto \bar\omega=\omega^2$.

Then $\sigma\tau: a \mapsto a \mapsto a\omega$ and $\tau\sigma: a \mapsto a\omega \mapsto a\omega^2$.

So, the Galois group has order $6$ and is not abelian. It must then be $S_3$.

Comment: I would have to say its isomorphic to $S_3$ technically, correct?

Comment: @NinosławCiszewski, sure.